# reverse-reverse of Michael selection theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a compact and $Y=\mathbb R^d.$ Let $\Gamma:X\twoheadrightarrow Y$  be a multi-valued map with closed values. Assume that $\Gamma$ admits a continuous (single-valued) selector. Can we conclude that $\Gamma$ is measurable?

I call this the reverse-reverse of Michael selection theorem since the reverse of this theorem says that if $\Gamma$ is continuous and admits a continuous selector, then $X$ must be compact. So what I want is a sort of reverse-reverse of this last statement...

Comment: How is measurability for multi-valued maps defined?

Comment: I doubt that such a thing is true. Let $\Gamma$ be any non measurable map with closed values, bounded away from $0$. Then $\Gamma'(x) := \Gamma(x) \cup\{0\}$ has a continuous selector, but is non-measurable.

Comment: Thanks! A concrete example would be helpful, but I think your reasoning is going into the right direction...